Averageif bottom n if not blank
I'd like to find the average of the bottom n (3 in this case) of a range. These will be golf scores and updated weekly. It will be 3 weeks before I have 3 numbers in the range, but I will need an average before that too. Eventually there will be 9 numbers and I'll want the average of the smallest 3. I guess it's kind of like a running average.



A
B
C
D
E
F
G
H
I




40
42










For this example, I'd like the average to be 41.



A
B
C
D
E
F
G
H
I




40
39
43
45
48







For this example, I'd like the average to be 40.7, using the 3 smallest (40,39,43).
I have triedAVERAGE(SMALL(A1:I1,{1,2,3})), but it only works if I have at least 3 values.I've also tried AVERAGEIF(A1:I1,""), but that just gives me the overall average, not the low 3. I tried inserting the AVERAGE(SMALL(A1:I1,{1,2,3})) in the AVERAGEIF function, but I get an error. Let me know if you need more info.

using the 3 smallest (40,39,43) means only first 3 numbers. If it is smallest 3 then it would be (38,39,40). Please clarify.

What about =AVERAGE(TAKE(A1:I1,,3))?

I edited my question, meant 48, not 38. The =AVERAGE(TAKE(A1:I1,,3)) works. I can't mark it as the correct answer, but I appreciate it

I have posted the formula as answer.

=AVERAGE(SMALL(A1:I1, SEQUENCE(3)))

Give a try to the following formula-
=AVERAGE(TAKE(A1:I1,,3))



A Current Average of a Maximum of N Lowest Values
List (in cell J2)
Single Row (Copy Down)
=AVERAGE(TAKE(SORT(A2:I2,,,1),,3))

Multiple Rows (Spills)
=BYROW(A2:I10,LAMBDA(r,AVERAGE(TAKE(SORT(r,,,1),,3))))

Screenshot

Table (in first data cell of column AVG (J13))
=AVERAGE(TAKE(SORT(Table1[@[A]:[I]],,,1),,3))

